# How to set up Contour Integration

Tags: mathematical-physics, contour-integration

So I am evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{z^2dz}{(z^2-4)(z^2+9)}$.

The residues for the four poles at $\pm2,\,\pm3i$ give$$\operatorname{Res}_{\pm2}(f)=\pm\frac{1}{13},\,\operatorname{Res}_{\pm3i}=\frac{\mp3i}{26}.$$

From here I am unsure of how to continue or if I have set this up correctly, I do know the expected result is $\frac{3\pi}{26}$ however I am unsure of how to get there.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Something wrong here. Your integral does not exist.

Comment: $3\pi/26$ is the PV. The integral itself is not convergent.

Comment: As @Обжоров mentioned, the integral should be understood in the principal value sense. You can do, for example, the following:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{z^2dz}{(z^2-4)(z^2+9)}=\frac{1}{13}\int_0^\infty\big(\frac{4}{z^2-4}+\frac{9}{z^2+9}\big)dz=\frac{1}{13}\int_0^\infty\big(\frac{2}{t^2-1}+\frac{3}{t^2+1}\big)dt$$
The second integral is straightforward; in the first one just make the change $t=\frac{1}{x}$
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2-1}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=-I\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,I=0$$

Comment: The integral was supposed to have x's as z's